# valgrind error - printf from fgets

Tags: c, valgrind, fgets

I am trying to read a line from a file and print it.

```
char *readLine(int n, FILE *file) {
    int i;
    int BUF=255;
    char temp[BUF];
    char puffer[BUF];
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    if(fgets(temp, BUF, file) == NULL)
        return NULL; 

    if(fgets(puffer,BUF,file) == NULL)
        return NULL; 
    return puffer; 
}
```

I do not get errors if I do following:

```
char * temp=readLine(2,somefile);
```

but as soon as I

```
printf("%s",temp);
```

valgrind returns following error

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
at 0x402EC04:strcrnul(in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable corrupt after returning from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247884/why-is-my-variable-corrupt-after-returning-from-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an array of characters that lives on the stack. When `readLine` finishes executing, the memory for `puffer` is automatically gone.

You need to allocate memory on the heap. One quick fix is to do this:

```
char *readLine(int n, FILE *file) {
int i;
int BUF=255;
char temp[BUF];
char puffer[BUF];
char* returned_string;
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    if(fgets(temp, BUF, file) == NULL)
        return NULL; 

if(fgets(puffer,BUF,file) == NULL)
    return NULL; 

returned_string = malloc (strlen (puffer) + 1);
strcpy (returned_string, puffer);

return returned_string; 
}
```

You don't really need two buffers in your function, though.

Comment: As I said, it's not a very elegant solution. You can use only one buffer in your function, not two. Also, don't forget to free the allocated memory when you no longer need the string, or you'll have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You have to malloc the neccessary memory. Now you are returning a pointer to a variable on the function stack. That will probably not exist anymore after the function returns, therefore you exibit undefined behavior.

change

```
char puffer[BUF];
```

into

```
char* puffer = malloc(BUF);
```

and don't forget to free this memory after you are ready with this.